# Show that $\ker A\subseteq\ker A^2$ and $\operatorname{Im} A^2\subseteq \operatorname{Im} A$.

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group and let $A: G \to G$ be a homomorphism. Let $B: G \to G$ defined by $B(x)=A(A(x))$ be a homomorphism as well.

Show that the kernel of $A$ is contained in the kernel of $B$ and that the image of $B$ is contained in the image of $A$.

My idea is to pick a element from the kernel of $A$ and showing that it's contained in $ker(B)$ as well. Is this the right idea?

Comment: Yes, that's the right idea.

Comment: Another question. assuming G is finite, which isomorphism theorem concludes that: 
ker(A)=ker(B) implies im(A)=im(B)
I have a really hard time to understand the theorems, so i have no clue on how to prove this. Hope someone can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x\in\ker A$. Then $A(x)=1$ and so $B(x)=A(A(x))=A(1)=1$ since $A$ is a homomorphism. Thus $x\in\ker B$. Hence $\ker A\subseteq \ker B$.

---

Let $y\in\operatorname{Im}(B)$. Then $y=B(z)$ for some $z\in G$. But then $y=B(z)=A(A(z))=A(t),$ where $t=A(z)$. Thus $y\in\operatorname{Im}(A)$. Hence $\operatorname{Im}(B)\subseteq \operatorname{Im}(A)$.

Comment: Does that make sense to you, @LilcoNe?

Comment: Yes that's perfect, i can accept your answer in 4 minutes.